# Don't include all javascript files rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I created a site and some javascript and css files that I only use on one site (they would disturb functions on other sites), but I don't know how to exclude the files from the asset pipeline.

In the asset javascript folder I created a new folder called paint that contains all javascript files I don't want to load on all sites. But only on one specific site.

Also I created a folder in assets stylesheetsy directory for the stylesheet I only need on the specific site.

My application.js looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require fancybox
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_self
```

I hope somebody can help me! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
//= require_tree .
```

And require only the files that you need